# Remove Pan control in Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any way to remove the circular panning navigation control but keep the zoom control in the Google Maps V3 API?  I've tried forcing it offscreen with jQuery but every time the map is updated it comes back.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL` to display a small plus/minus zoom control, otherwise you'll have to create your own zoom control and add it to the map.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You may also have a look in here, you can remove/add specific controls when you declare your map:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.44062, -79.99588);
var options = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: latlng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

[Taking Control of the Google Maps API V3 Controls](http://www.developer.com/services/taking-control-of-the-google-maps-api-v3-controls.html)

Answer (score 6):

In V3, when you define your options - you have the option of disabling/enabling any UI features:

```
function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
            //panControl: false,
            zoomControl: false,
            scaleControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
}
```